# Does Apple allow us to block incoming GSM calls programmatically?

Tags: ios

I am trying to build an app that block incoming GSM calls based on some criteria.
We have CallKit to handle and block calls for VOIP apps but that not what I need.
I want my app to be able to block GSM calls.
Is that allowed by Apple?
On Android, it can be done in many ways like adding number to the phone block list.
Are there any way to achieve blocking number on iOS?
Thanks

Comment: You can use a CallKit extension to provide a list of numbers to be blocked to iOS.  You cannot gain access to the incoming call details in order to determine, dynamically, if the call should be blocked. https://github.com/paulw11/CallKitTutorial

Comment: Thank you @Paulw11 . You mean using this CallKit extension I can provide iOS with the list of numbers to be blocked even on GSM calls? or you mean in-app voip calls only?

Comment: Callkit extension blocks gsm calls.

Comment: @Paulw11 I guess you just answered my question, i will give it a try but as it is a comment I can't mark your reply as an answer. Thank you!